# Use LINQ in C# to find MondoDB records when values in a list field match a criteria value from a list

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to use LINQ to return all records in a MongoDB collection where the field in the record is a list of strings and any string in the list matches any string value in a list of strings used as the search criteria:

Mongo Record in Collection ("Item"):

```
{
    "_id": ...,
    "StringList": [
        "string1",
        "string2",
        "string3"
    ],
    ...
}
```

Search Criteria:

```
var criteria = new List<string> { "string2", "string4" };
```

My Code:

```
var foundItems = iMongoDataProvider.FindAll<Item>()
                           .Where(x =>x.StringList.ContainsAny(criteria)).ToList();
```

Based on the above, the Mongo record should be returned since one of the *StringList* values matches one of the values in the search *criteria*.  Nothing is returned even though I can manually peruse the collection and find the matching record.  What am I doing wrong?  Can someone provide an example that will do what I need?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `ElemMatch` Filter (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) :

```
var foundItems = collection.Find(Builders<Item>.Filter.ElemMatch(
                     x => x.StringList,
                     s=>criteria.Contains(s)));
```

where collection is  your `IMongoCollection<Item>`
I see, that you are using `FindAll`, that means, that your MongoDb driver is of the version 1.x  (see here more about it:  [FindAll in MongoDB .NET Driver 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829282/findall-in-mongodb-net-driver-2-0))
I would suggest to update your  driver, because this version isnot uptodate. Or are the any important reason don't to do it?

This filter query on server. Sure you could get your data as IEnumerable and filter it locally:

```
var foundItems = collection.Find(x=>true)
                   .ToEnumerable()
                   .Where(x => x.StringList.Intersect(criteria).Any());
```

If your data is not so huge and you are fine with filtering on client it's a good way too.

And if you are doing already `FindAll`, that means you get get all the data, you could  query it with `intersect` :

```
var foundItems = iMongoDataProvider.FindAll<Item>()
                           .Where(x => x.StringList.Intersect(criteria).Any());
```

Comment: Tried to use your first suggestion, but got a `Cannot resolve symbol 'Builders'`; got the same message for `ToEnumerable` for your second suggestion.  Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: @MarkLinebarger You are missing new version of the driver, i have updated my answer. Sorry, all what i wrote was for the 2.x  MongoDb c#  drvier

Comment: We are on version 1.11.0.92.  We have not done any research on the differences when upgrading to 2.x (and any issues it may cause), so I cannot upgrade without consulting the team.  I do know that `FindAll` is used in many places throughout our solution; if that changed dramatically, it's not worth changing to resolve this one issue.  I do know that my code works if I find all based on **one** of the _criteria_ entries; i.e.: `var foundItems = iMongoDataProvider.FindAll<Item>().Where(x => x.StringList.Contains(criteria[0])).ToList();`

Comment: @MarkLinebarger  I have updated my answer, as i understood FindAlljust gives you all Items, so it's not mongodb, but Linq question and intersect query should give valid results.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried somethinglike:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

var foundItems = _collection.FindAll(x=> criteria.Any(cc=> xx.StringList.Contains(cc))).ToList();
```

Where `_collection` is  `IMongoCollection<TEntity> _collection`

Comment: is the variable `xx` declared?

Comment: I don't understand this response.  As @Hogan asked yesterday, I see no declaration for `xx`... should that be `x`?  If so, then that didn't work.  Please explain.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is to know if the intersection of the two lists has any values:

```
 .Where(x =>x.StringList.Intersect(criteria).Any())
```

---

I'm not sure what the problem is with your code but here is working code

```
void Main()
{
    List<string> []StringList = new List<string>[] {
             new List<string> {    "string1", "string2", "string3" },
             new List<string> {    "string11", "string12", "string13" },
             new List<string> {    "string21", "string22", "string4" }
    };

    var criteria = new List<string> { "string2", "string4" };

    var foundItems = StringList
                      .Where(x => x.Intersect(criteria).Any()).ToList();

    foundItems.Dump();
}
```

I tested this using LinqPad (which I recommend to anyone working in Linq and it is free).

Comment: This, from the looks of it, seemed like my best option, but I get this error when running: "Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: Enumerable.Intersect<String>(x.StringList, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String])."  I am missing something.

Comment: @MarkLinebarger not sure, I'd have to see all the source to be sure but it should be the same as `.Where(x => criteria.Intersect(x.StringList).Any())` does that give you the same error?

Comment: I get the same general error... here is the full error for the second try:    'System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233067
  Message=Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: Enumerable.Intersect<String>(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String], x.StringList).
  Source=MongoDB.Driver'

Comment: @MarkLinebarger -- see my edit -- how is your code different from this working example?

Comment: Perhaps my issue is trying to do this with MondoDB.  As noted in my original question, I am perusing a collection in Mongo that includes a field (_StringList_) that is an array of strings.  In the code (above), I'm trying to `FindAll` items where **any value** found in the string array matches **any value** that can be found in the List<string> (_criteria_).  I don't know if MongoDB.Drivers allow for this type of Linq expression.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: @MarkLinebarger -- oh yeah Maksim Simkin explained it well in his answer, use that.

Comment: His suggestion requires updating our MongoDB drivers; I will be checking into that.  Thanks for your help.